# How to fix host name issue in Hbase

Tags: hbase

When I was using Spark to scan table from Hbase, I met the following WARN information, but it's not an exception, I still be able to query out the data from Hbase:

```
WARN mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase: 
Cannot resolve the host name for h006.test.test.local/10.1.1.6 because of 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3];
remaining name '10.1.1.6.in-addr.arpa'
```

Should I setup a DNS sever specially for Hbase please? Thanks!

Comment: maybe a /etc/hosts file config would be sufficent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hbase is using dns loopup to get the actual IP of domain, if there is no mapping in your dns server, it would throw that WARN messages. It's no matter with /etc/host.